# vb.net alternatives to php file handeling functions?

Tags: php, vb.net

i need vb.net equivlants of php fopen, fseek, and fwrite... also, i need to read and write data, not just text. I need to write data at specific byte position to x amount of bytes, as well as read at byte position to x amount of bytes...

Comment: I usually can find good results when searching for things like "MSDN seek file". The "MSDN" bit is important and an applicable .NET API namespace/class/method is normally returned in the first few results when it is present. The above search found [FileStream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx). Get reading, and pay attention to the notes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes look at the System.IO.File class.
use the 'Open' method to get a FileStream. This has the functions your looking for i.e. seek,read,write

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file_members(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.filestream.write(v=vs.80).aspx